# What is the difference between av_register_all() vs avcodec_register_all() in ffmpeg c api?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I am a beginner to ffmpeg and libavcodec in c programming on a linux machine. I want to know the difference between these API's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`av_register_all`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/allformats_8c_source.html#l00051) registers absolutely everything - i.e. muxers, demuxers and protocols + it calls to [`avcodec_register_all`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/allcodecs_8c_source.html#l00068). `avcodec_register_all` only registers codecs. Bare codecs are seldom useful as such.